# Are SQL Server timeouts logged?

Tags: sql-server, timeout, error-log

Are SQL Server timeouts (SELECT queries, in particular) logged in the ERRORLOG file?

Background is a customer with a web site having occasional "Request timeout" messages, looking to me assuming that the timeout is caused by a database timeout.  There are no timeout errors in the ERRORLOG in question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. You will need to use SQL Profiler. A standard trace with the **Lock Timeout** event and **Deadlock Graph** events should do it.

- [Lock:Timeout Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189107.aspx)
- [Deadlock Graph Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177409.aspx)

Hardware aside (such as enough RAM and fast drives, and appropriate placement of Data and Log files on the appropriate RAID configurations) most timeouts are caused by not having a sufficently 'good' set of indexes for your workload.

Do you have index maintenance plans scheduled regularly?

Comment: Thanks for that, I've set a trace going...
I don't have regular index maintenance, but I did defrag them last week and the problem is still occurring.

Comment: as i said profiler trace might cause performance issues if left for a while to run. depending of course on your system load.

Comment: A properly set up trace should roughly consume less than 5% of CPU and resources. This post will show you how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257906/ms-sql-server-2008-how-can-i-log-and-find-the-most-expensive-queries#257944

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server timeouts are *initiated* from the client-side as **Attention Events** and are not recorded in the SQL Server Error Log.

You can monitor for Attention Events using:

- [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190979.aspx)
- The DMV [sys.dm_os_ring_buffers](http://www.johnsansom.com/using-sys-dm_os_ring_buffers-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues/)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Event Notifications that get raised on the timeout and deadlock events. After it fires, you can write it to a table and or send yourself an email.

I've shown the general technique here:

> ### [Immediate deadlock notifications without changing existing code](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/07/18/Immediate-deadlock-notifications-without-changing-existing-code.aspx)
>
> July 18, 2008

This way you don't have to run Profiler; which can impact performance.