# Track SQL queries that timeout

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to query SQL Server 2008 R2 for a list of queries that have timedout?

I'm trying to find out which parts of our app are falling over, but for boring and bad reasons that won't get fixed, we have no application level logging.

In lieu of getting some application logging put in, how can I find out which queries are timing out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Timeout Logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295299/sql-server-timeout-logging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to get all the time-outs you will need to use the profiler, however you can run some queries that may help:

show top 10 high CPU queries:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time
        ,execution_count
        ,total_elapsed_time/execution_count as AVG_Run_Time
        ,(SELECT
              SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2,(CASE
                                                           WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2 
                                                           ELSE statement_end_offset 
                                                       END -statement_start_offset)/2
                       ) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
         ) AS query_text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
ORDER BY Avg_CPU_Time DESC
```

this query will show cahced query plans that "SCAN", change comments for other things, can add filters for UseCount, EstimatedCost, EstimatedCPU, Estimated Rows

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
, CachedPlans AS
(SELECT
     RelOp.op.value(N'../../@NodeId', N'int') AS ParentOperationID
         ,RelOp.op.value(N'@NodeId', N'int') AS OperationID
         ,RelOp.op.value(N'@PhysicalOp', N'varchar(50)') AS PhysicalOperator
         ,RelOp.op.value(N'@LogicalOp', N'varchar(50)') AS LogicalOperator
         ,RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost ', N'float') AS EstimatedCost
         ,RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateIO', N'float') AS EstimatedIO
         ,RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateCPU', N'float') AS EstimatedCPU
         ,RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateRows', N'float') AS EstimatedRows
         ,cp.plan_handle AS PlanHandle
         ,qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan
         ,st.TEXT AS QueryText
         ,cp.cacheobjtype AS CacheObjectType
         ,cp.objtype AS ObjectType
         ,cp.usecounts AS UseCounts
     FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans                            cp
         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle)     st
         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle)   qp
         CROSS APPLY qp.query_plan.nodes(N'//RelOp')          RelOp (op)
)
SELECT
    PlanHandle
        ,ParentOperationID
        ,OperationID
        ,PhysicalOperator
        ,LogicalOperator
        ,UseCounts
        ,CacheObjectType
        ,ObjectType
        ,EstimatedCost
        ,EstimatedIO
        ,EstimatedCPU
        ,EstimatedRows
        ,QueryText
    FROM CachedPlans
    WHERE CacheObjectType = N'Compiled Plan'

AND PhysicalOperator IN ('nothing will ever match this one!'
                        --,'Assert'                             
                        --,'Bitmap'
                        --,'Clustered Index Delete'
                        --,'Clustered Index Insert'
                        ,'Clustered Index Scan'
                        --,'Clustered Index Seek'
                        --,'Clustered Index Update'
                        --,'Compute Scalar'
                        --,'Concatenation'
                        --,'Constant Scan'
                        ,'Deleted Scan'
                        --,'Filter'
                        --,'Hash Match'
                        ,'Index Scan'
                        --,'Index Seek'
                        --,'Index Spool'
                        ,'Inserted Scan'
                        --,'Merge Join'
                        --,'Nested Loops'
                        --,'Parallelism'
                        ,'Parameter Table Scan'
                        --,'RID Lookup'
                        --,'Segment'
                        --,'Sequence Project'
                        --,'Sort'
                        --,'Stream Aggregate'
                        --,'Table Delete'
                        --,'Table Insert'
                        ,'Table Scan'
                        --,'Table Spool'
                        --,'Table Update'
                        --,'Table-valued function'
                        --,'Top'
                        )
```

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, good thing I said "may help" ;-)  also, it isn't really CPU time, it is more like actual time (`total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time`).  the system view I use: `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` has columns for: `max_elapsed_time`, `last_rows`, `max_physical_reads`, etc which can be be evaluated as well.