# How can I capture queries that fail on the SQL Server due to connection drops/failures?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, networking, database-connection

How can I capture queries that fail on the SQL Server due to connection drops/failures?

Profiler doesnt seem to capture if there is a connectivity loss.

Comment: What is calling the query? Is it an SQL job or a bit of code?

Comment: A third party service on which I dont have much control/cannot change

Answer (score 0):

Without catching the exception in the code this is not the easiest thing to do.

- Have you checked the error logs in SQL? DA has a related answer for doing this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/sql-server-error-log-monitoring
- You can check that your profiler is set up correctly:
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224587
- There are a number of sql monitoring tools out there, just google 'SQL server monitoring'.

Comment: 1. Error logs dont show which query failed due to network failure
2. That link doesnt talk much about profiling for network issues
3. There are just too many

Comment: In that case try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295299/sql-server-timeout-logging along with this article: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server-profiler/gathering-deadlock-information-with-deadlock-graph