# Refactoring "extreme" SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, refactoring

I have a business user who tried his hand at writing his own SQL query for a report of project statistics (e.g. number of tasks, milestones, etc.). The query starts off declaring a temp table of 80+ columns. There are then almost 70 UPDATE statements to the temp table over almost 500 lines of code that each contain their own little set of business rules. It finishes with a SELECT * from the temp table.

Due to time constraints and 'other factors', this was rushed into production and now my team is stuck with supporting it. Performance is appalling, although thanks to some tidy up it's fairly easy to read and understand (although the code smell is nasty).

What are some key areas we should be looking at to make this faster and follow good practice?

Comment: Add this info to the main article, and tag appropriately it if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, if this is not causing a business problem, then leave it until it becomes a problem.  Wait until it becomes a problem, then fix everything.

When you do decide to fix it, check if there is one statement causing most of your speed issues ... issolate and fix it.

If the speed issue is over all the statements, and you can combine it all into a single SELECT, this will probably save you time.  I once converted a proc like this (not as many updates) to a SELECT and the time to run it went from over 3 minutes to under 3 seconds (no shit ... I couldn't believe it).  By the way, don't attempt this if some of the data is coming from a linked server.

If you don't want to or can't do that for whatever reason, then you might want to adjust the existing proc.  Here are some of the things I would look at:

1. If you are creating indexes on the temp table, wait until after your initial INSERT to populate it.
2. Adjust your initial INSERT to insert as many of the columns as possible.  There are probably some update's you can eliminate by doing this.
3. Index the temp table before running your updates.  Do not create indexes on any of the columns targetted by the update statements until after their updated.
4. Group your updates if your table(s) and groupings allow for it.  70 updates is quite a few for only 80 columns, and sounds like there may be an opportunity to do this.

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

First thing I would do is check to make sure there is an active index maintenance job being run periodically. If not, get all existing indexes rebuilt or if not possible at least get statistics updated.

Second thing I would do is set up a trace (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257906/ms-sql-server-2008-how-can-i-log-and-find-the-most-expensive-queries#257944)) and find out which statements are causing the highest number of reads.

Then I would run in SSMS with 'show actual execution plan' and tally the results with the trace. From this you should be able to work out whether there are missing indexes that could improve performance.

EDIT: If you are going to downvote, please leave a comment as to why.

Answer (score 2):

Just like any refactoring, make sure you have an automated way to verify your refactorings after each change (you can write this yourself using queries which check the development output against a known good baseline).  That way, you are always matching the known good data.  This will give you a high degree of confidence in the correctness of your approach when you enter the phase where you are deciding whether to switch over to your new version of the process and want to run side by side for a few iterations to ensure correctness.

I also like to log all the test batches and the run times of the processes within the batch, so I can tell if some particular process within the batch was adversely affected at some point in time.  I can get average times for processes and see trends of improvement or spot potential problems.  This also lets me identify the low-hanging fruit within the batch where I can make the most improvement.

Answer (score 2):

> There are then almost 70 UPDATE
>   statements to the temp table over
>   almost 500 lines of code that each
>   contain their own little set of
>   business rules. It finishes with a
>   SELECT * from the temp table.

Actually this sounds like it can be followed and understood quite well, each update statement does one thing to the table with a specific purpose and set of business rules. I think that maintaining procedures of 500 lines of code with one or a couple of select statements that does "everything", built with 15 or so joins, and case statements etc scattered all over the place, is a lot harder to maintain. Although it would make for better performance..

It's a bit of a dilemma with SQL, that writing clear and concise code (using multiple updates, creating functions etc) always seems to have a big negative impact on performance. Trying to do everything at once, which is considered bad practice in other programming languages, seems to be the very core of set oriented languages.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the only thing you've told us about this stored procedure is that it has a 80+ column temp table, the only thing I can recommend is to remove that table, and rewrite the rest to remove the need for it.

Comment: Thanks James, provided more detail in the question now.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a report generating stored procedure, how often is it being run? If it's only necessary to run it once a day and is run during the night how much of an issue is the performance?

If it's not I'd recommend being careful in your choice to re-write it because there is a chance that you could muck up your figures.

Also it sounds like the sort of thing that should be pulled out into an SSIS package building up a new permanent table with the results so it only has to be run once.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is to replace the temp table with a table variable. There are times when this is faster and times when it is not, you will have to just try it and see.

Look at the 70 update statements. It is possible to combine any of them? If the person writing did not use CASE statments, it might be possible to do fewer statements.

Other obvious things to look at - eliminate any cursors, change any subqueries to joins to tables or derived tables.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite perhaps.  One hardware solution would be to make sure your database temp table goes on a 'fast' drive, perhaps a solid state disk (SSD), or can be managed all in memory.

My guess is this 'solution' was developed by someone with a grasp of and a dependency upon spreadsheets, someone who may not be very savvy on 'normalized' databases--how to construct and populate tables to retain data for reporting purposes, something which perhaps BI Business Intelligence software can be utilized with sophistication and yet be adaptable.

You didn't say 'where' the update process is being run.  Is the update process being run as a SQL script from a separate computer (desktop) against the server where the data is?  There can be significant bottlenecks and overhead created by that approach. If so, consider running the entire update process directly on the server as a local job, as a compiled stored procedure, bypassing the network and (multiple) cursor management overhead.  It could have a scheduled time to run and a controlled priority, completing in off peak business data usage hours.

Evaluate how often 'commit' statements are really needed for the sequence of update statements...saving on a bunch of commit lines could notably improve the overall update time.  There may be a couple of settings in the database client driver software which can make a notable difference.

Can the queries used for update conditions be factored out as static 'views' which in turn can be shared across multiple update statements?  Views can keep in memory data/query rows frequently accessed. There may be performance tuning in determining how much update data can be pended before a commit is optimal.

It might be worth evaluating whether Triggers could be used to replace the batch job update sequence.  You don't say from how many tables the data used comes from...that might help with decision making.  I don't know if you have the option of adding triggers to the database tables from which the data is gathered.  If so, adding a few triggers to a number of tables wouldn't really degrade overall system performance much, but might save a big wad of time on that update process. You could try replacing the update statements one at a time with triggers and see if the results are the same as before.  Create a similar temp table, based on the same update process, then carefully test whether triggers feeding updates to the temp table could replace individual update statements.  Perhaps you may have a sort of 'Data Warehouse' application.  It might be useful to review how to set up a 'star' schema of tables to retain summarized business data for reporting.

Creating a comprehensive and cached 'view' which updates via the queries once per day, reflecting the updates might be another approach to explore.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a tool that allows you to get an explain plan of all queries your app will run. It is the best bang for the buck on an SQL heavy app for performace increases. If you read and react to what the Explain Plan is telling you. If you are on Oracle what we used to use was TOAD by Qwest(?) I think. It was a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the tables involved, the end result, and  starting from scratch to see if the query can be done in a more efficient manner.  Keep the query to verify that the new one is working exactly the same as the old one, but try to forget all methods used to obtain the end result.

Answer (score -1):

I would rewrite it from scratch.

You say that you understand what it supposed to do so it should not be that difficult. And I bet that the requirements for that piece of code will keep changing so if you do not rewrite it now you may end up maintaining some ugly monster

Comment: OK, but if you've already got buggy code, new code might at least be easier to maintain long-term.

Comment: The poster didn't say it was buggy, only that performance was terrible.