# MySQL Server vs XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql-workbench

I just migrated my table to MySQL Server 5.6 in order to get full use of my system memory since XAMPP doesn't allow you to do so because its MySQL is based on a 32-bit arch. I also downloaded MySQL Workbench to control my server. HOWEVER, all of my queries take almost 2 seconds longer than when I had my server running on XAMPP profile. I activate my old server and everything is back to normal...

I checked all of the configuration variables and have set them exactly the same and still nothing changes.

Is there something I'm not seeing understanding here?

Answer (score 0):

Which engines do you use?

How large are your tables?

Maybe this helps
[When should database indexes be rebuilt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321461/when-should-database-indexes-be-rebuilt)

Comment: The database is a little over 6MB so the tables aren't that big. I have a mix of MYISAM WITH INNODB , but mostly INNODB.

Comment: you could use a profiler to dedect the steps which do actually take a long time. I know phpMyAdmin offers an easy to use possibility. also look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profile.html