# Mysql running different indexes on different servers

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

The problem we are facing is we have a query then runs in 6-7 seconds on our master DB but on our slave DB this can take upwards of 5+ mins.

I have found that the execution plan for the query is different when executing on the master than the slave. The difference being that on one of the tables the slave DB is using a different index than what the master is using.

What’s more is when I execute this very same query from command line in putty on the slave database it actually uses the same execution plan as the master DB. The execution plan only changes when the query comes from our front end application and is executed on the slave DB.

As a quick fix I put in a FORCE INDEX into the sql to use the index the master uses, this seemed to make a partial fix in terms that only 1 part of the multi index seemed to be used. The master DB uses a key length of 7 whereas the slave uses a key length of 4.

The query in question is a very large query with multiple joins. It is on one of the joins that the index is going astray and using a different index. This is also where I have put the force index.

We are using Mysql with MyISAM tables.

My question is, is what can cause this behaviour and why is it that when the exact same query runs fine when executed from command line?

Comment: are you using mysql or sql-server? you tagged both. probably the quickest way to get the problem located is to generate the create scripts for the relevant db, tables and related objects and run a diff on them

Comment: I would suggest you consider the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321461/when-should-database-indexes-be-rebuilt

Comment: @Tristan We are using Mysql with MyISAM tables(I have updated the post to include this information now as well). I didn’t know about the diff command, I will have a look into this thank you.

Comment: I'm only proficient with sql-server myself but what you could also look for are schema compare tools that fit your system. It's basically the same thing as running a diff on the scripts but with much more sql specific functions. Just google "mysql schema compare"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would answer this encase anyone ever has the same problem, we discovered that the answer to our problem was that we setting the following in our connection to the database

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci';");
```

Or in codeigniter.

```
$db['slave']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

However our tables are set to use latin1 and not UTF8, as soon as we took out this setting our 5+ min queries completely stopped and ran in similar times to the master.
Hope this helps someone in the future.