# MySQL query on medium-sized table fast on one system, slow on another

Tags: mysql, windows, macos, performance

I have the following table with about 40k rows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_ui_activity` (
    `uiActivityLogEntryId` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment ,
    `uid` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    `from` DATETIME,
    `duration` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    `nCharactersTyped` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    `nClicks` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    `hadOtherInteractions` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    `currentPage` TEXT,
    `currentPageArgs` TEXT,
    `currentPageStateInfo` TEXT,
    `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`uiActivityLogEntryId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

with two additional indices, each on `createdAt` and `uid`.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM log_ui_activity
    WHERE `createdAt` IN (
        SELECT MAX(`createdAt`) FROM log_ui_activity
                  GROUP BY uid);
```

It finishes within 0.2s on Windows 7 and running XAMPP with:

> MySql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.20, for Win32 (x86)

However, it takes several minutes when running the exact same query on an exact copy of the data on a Mac Pro (verified: structure, indices and engine are all the same) running MAMP with:

> MySql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for osx10.6 (i386) using  EditLine wrapper

I have even tried different clients...

Any ideas how the query can be so much slower, even though everything is/appears to be identical?

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the answer, using `JOIN` instead of `IS IN` fixes things. For reference, this is the `JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT *
    FROM log_ui_activity a
    INNER JOIN (
    (SELECT MAX(`createdAt`) createdAt FROM log_ui_activity GROUP BY uid) tmp
    )
    ON (a.createdAt = tmp.createdAt);
```

Comment: If you do an EXPLAIN on each system are the results the same? Have you rebuilt the indexes recently on both systems?

Comment: @Kickstart Thanks for the info! `EXPLAIN` shows the same. However, I thought, creating an index on an existing table (using `CREATE INDEX`) would actually build the index. I also find that InnoDB does not support [REPAIR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repair-table.html), so I am now trying the `mysqldump` method instead.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the actual indexes, rather the statistics that MySQL uses to decide which indexes to use. This other reply may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321461/when-should-database-indexes-be-rebuilt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` used to have terrible performance.  You could usually 'fix' it by turning it into a `JOIN`.  The problem was that the `SELECT` would be re-executed every time the `IN` was needed.

[In 5.6.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html#subquery-materialization), the optimizer does something fancier.  You can see the 'change' by doing `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...`, then `SHOW WARNINGS`.

Comment: Just tested it. Using `INNER JOIN` instead of `IS IN`, makes the query execute in 93ms. Noticing that sort of subtle difference between versions; that is quite some insight, thanks! - Oh also, I accidentally undid and redid your edit on my question, but SO seems to have a bug that it would not accredit you anymore in this case. - Sorry! Feel free, to make another edit :)

Comment: Glad to hear it is running fast.  93ms vs 0.2s implies that the JOIN doubled the speed; this is interesting to know.  Thanks for the followup.  No problem (about the edit); anyway, the revision history shows the details.

Comment: Sorry! The 93ms is from the Mac Pro which is faster than the Windows PC, where it took 200ms. So I just double-checked, and turns out, yes: The JOIN is faster still. On the Windows PC (newer MySQL version), the `IS IN` takes between 150 and 220ms, and the `JOIN` version takes between 90 and 150ms. NOTE: I only repeated the query several times, and took note of the query times; not really a very reliable setup for performance testing.