# Is there a tool online to optimize a stored procedure or inline sql

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have many complex SQL queries that I would like to optimize. The performance on it is pretty bad. Is there an online tool to optimize such queries?

Comment: Anything that can be optimised by a tool will probably be optimised by the database's optimiser already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about MS SQL Server, then Yes: SQL Profiler is part of SQL Server.

Optimizing is not the easiest thing to do!

This might be of help: [MS SQL Server 2008 - How Can I Log and Find the Most Expensive Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257906/ms-sql-server-2008-how-can-i-log-and-find-the-most-expensive-queries)