# When using of full text indexing in sql server give me better performance? In every where or in some situations?

Tags: sql-server, performance, nhibernate, full-text-indexing

I write a big application by using of NHibernate ORM. Is using of full text indexing in DB level has advantages for my application performance? does it give me better performance in searches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will turning on SQL Server Full Text searching speed up your NHibernate generated queries? No.

Creating standard indexes to cover your query workload might.

To identify your most expensive queries: [How Can I Log and Find the Most Expensive Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257906/ms-sql-server-2008-how-can-i-log-and-find-the-most-expensive-queries)