# SQL Server - Detecting non-indexed columns but used in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, database-administration

How to detect a column included in WHERE clause but used in indexed?

**Little Background:**

Until the time the table has few number of records things will be okay, once it started having millions of records then index should be created for a column which is used in WHERE clauses in stored procs, inline queries etc.,

Since we have hundreds of stored procs and queries that often gets changed by the devs I wanted to have a automated way of identifying those columns that are used in WHERE clauses but not an index is created. How to do that in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "Missing indexes" dmv stuff to spot what could be added?

- [Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/bartd/archive/2007/07/19/are-you-using-sql-s-missing-index-dmvs.aspx) (this is weighted so you have an idea of cost too)
- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345524.aspx)

Edit: I'll qualify... this allows you to consider indexes based on cost/use/benefit.
An index may only be used at 04:00 on a Sunday, so from a cost perspective it's probably not worth it

Answer (score 0):

You should first identify your expensive queries: [How Can I Log and Find the Most Expensive Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257906/ms-sql-server-2008-how-can-i-log-and-find-the-most-expensive-queries)