# Use MS SQL Server Profiler to see which stored procedures are running slowly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-profiler

I have a basic knowledge about Microsoft SQL Server Profiler but I want to know that can I monitor a production environment to see which stored procedures are affecting performance by executing too slowly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Log and Find the Most Expensive Queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257906/how-can-i-log-and-find-the-most-expensive-queries)

Comment: You probably should look into plan cache first, it stores quite a lot of performance related information without having to setup anything extra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Profile is very bad for using it in production environment. It could be cause of performance degradation. I could recommend to you two ways

1. [Extended events](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354(v=sql.105).aspx)
2. [Trace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191443(v=sql.105).aspx)

I prefer first one. You can find a lot of information and examples how to use both of them