# How do I troubleshoot performance problems with an Oracle SQL statement

Tags: database, performance, oracle

I have two insert statements, almost exactly the same, which run in two different schemas on the same Oracle instance. What the insert statement looks like doesn't matter - I'm looking for a troubleshooting strategy here.

Both schemas have 99% the same structure. A few columns have slightly different names, other than that they're the same. The insert statements are almost exactly the same. The explain plan on one gives a cost of 6, the explain plan on the other gives a cost of 7. The tables involved in both sets of insert statements have exactly the same indexes. Statistics have been gathered for both schemas.

One insert statement inserts 12,000 records in 5 seconds.

The other insert statement inserts 25,000 records in 4 minutes 19 seconds.

The number of records being insert is correct. It's the vast disparity in execution times that confuses me. Given that nothing stands out in the explain plan, how would you go about determining what's causing this disparity in runtimes?

(I am using Oracle 10.2.0.4 on a Windows box).

**Edit:** The problem ended up being an inefficient query plan, involving a cartesian merge which didn't need to be done. Judicious use of index hints and a hash join hint solved the problem. It now takes 10 seconds. Sql Trace / TKProf gave me the direction, as I it showed me how many seconds each step in the plan took, and how many rows were being generated. Thus TKPROF showed me:-

```
Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
  23690  NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=3310466 pr=17 pw=0 time=174881374 us)
  23690   NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3310464 pr=17 pw=0 time=174478629 us)
2160900    MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN (cr=102 pr=0 pw=0 time=6491451 us)
   1470     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TBL1 (cr=57 pr=0 pw=0 time=23978 us)
   8820      INDEX RANGE SCAN XIF5TBL1 (cr=16 pr=0 pw=0 time=8859 us)(object id 272041)
2160900     BUFFER SORT (cr=45 pr=0 pw=0 time=4334777 us)
   1470      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TBL1 (cr=45 pr=0 pw=0 time=2956 us)
   8820       INDEX RANGE SCAN XIF5TBL1 (cr=10 pr=0 pw=0 time=8830 us)(object id 272041)
  23690    MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TBL2 (cr=3310362 pr=17 pw=0 time=235116546 us)
  96565     INDEX RANGE SCAN XPK_TBL2 (cr=3219374 pr=3 pw=0 time=217869652 us)(object id 272084)
      0   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TBL3 (cr=2 pr=0 pw=0 time=293390 us)
      0    INDEX RANGE SCAN XIF1TBL3 (cr=2 pr=0 pw=0 time=180345 us)(object id 271983)
```

Notice the rows where the operations are MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN and BUFFER SORT. Things that keyed me into looking at this were the number of rows generated (over 2 million!), and the amount of time spent on each operation (compare to other operations).

Comment: A cloud and a watermelon are 99% the same - water... doesn't mean that they are equivalent.

I could have two huge queries that go for pages and change = to != and that can completely change the performance.

Comment: Mark - the insert statements were on two different schemas with exactly the same tables, with a few columns named differently. Data types were the same. The insert statement used the same tables, the same join strategy, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [SQL Trace facility and TKPROF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm#g33356).

Comment: Useful - seems like a good general extra troubleshooting tool, which is what I want this question to be about. As I've commented elsewhere on this question, we're looking at the tablespaces at the moment, but I'll get to this tool if that's fruitless.

Comment: This is the way to go, TRACE + TKPROF will tell you exactly what your session is doing and where its spending time.

Comment: tablespaces? I've never once found query problems by examining tablespaces.

Comment: Link is broken.  Anyone have a new link?

Answer (score 2):

The main culprits in insert slow downs are indexes, constraints, and oninsert triggers.  Do a test without as many of these as you can remove and see if it's fast.  Then introduce them back in and see which one is causing the problem.

I have seen systems where they drop indexes before bulk inserts and rebuild at the end -- and it's faster.

Comment: Both systems have exactly the same indexes, constraints and triggers. We're looking at the different tablespaces right now.

Comment: The point of dropping indexes and rebuilding is mostly to avoid disk seeks during the load.  As a bonus your index is guaranteed to not be fragmented afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to realize is that, as [the documentation says](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76965/c20a_opt.htm#16287), the cost you see displayed is relative to one of the query plans.  The costs for 2 different explains are **not** comparable.  Secondly the costs are based on an internal estimate.  As hard as Oracle tries, those estimates are not accurate.  Particularly not when the optimizer misbehaves.  Your situation suggests that there are two query plans which, according to Oracle, are very close in performance.  But which, in fact, perform very differently.

The actual information that you want to look at is the actual explain plan itself.  That tells you exactly how Oracle executes that query.  It has a lot of technical gobbeldy-gook, but what you really care about is knowing that it works from the most indented part out, and at each step it merges according to one of a small number of rules.  That will tell you what Oracle is doing differently in your two instances.

What next?  Well there are a variety of strategies to tune bad statements.  The first option that I would suggest, if you're in Oracle 10g, is to try their [SQL tuning advisor](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/AutomaticSQLTuning10g.php) to see if a more detailed analysis will tell Oracle the error of its ways.  It can then store that plan, and you will use the more efficient plan.

If you can't do that, or if that doesn't work, then you need to get into things like providing query hints, manual stored query outlines, and the like.  That is a complex topic.  This is where it helps to have a real DBA.  If you don't, then you'll want to start reading the [documentation](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/toc.htm), but be aware that there is a lot to learn.  (Oracle also has a SQL tuning class that is, or at least used to be, very good.  It isn't cheap though.)

Answer (score 1):

I've put up my general list of things to check to improve performance as an answer to another question:

[Favourite performance tuning tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783/sql-what-are-your-favorite-performance-tricks#103176)

... It might be helpful as a checklist, even though it's not Oracle-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with a previous poster that SQL Trace and tkprof are a good place to start.  I also highly recommend the book [Optimizing Oracle Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600527X), which discusses similar tools for tracing execution and analyzing the output.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Trace and tkprof are only good if you have access to theses tools. Most of the large companies that I do work for do not allow developers to access anything under the Oracle unix IDs.

I believe you should be able to determine the problem by first understanding the question that is being asked and by reading the explain plans for each of the queries. Many times I find that the big difference is that there are some tables and indexes that have not been analyzed.

Comment: Fair enough, although wouldn't that be a situation where you could work with a DBA to get this done for you? FWIW, I made sure all tables/indexes in the schema had statistics and all columns had histograms. I'd also read the explain plan, and couldn't narrow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Another good reference that presents a general technique for query tuning is the book [SQL Tuning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005733) by Dan Tow.

Answer (score 0):

When the performance of a sql statement isn't as expected / desired, one of the first things I do is to check the execution plan.

The trick is to check for things that aren't as expected. For example you might find table scans where you think an index scan should be faster or vice versa.

A point where the oracle optimizer sometimes takes a wrong turn are the estimates how many rows a step will return. If the execution plan expects 2 rows, but you know it will more like 2000 rows, the execution plan is bound to be less than optimal.

With two statements to compare you can obviously compare the two execution plans to see where they differ.

From this analysis, I come up with an execution plan that I think should be suited better. This is not an exact execution plan, but just some crucial changes, to the one I found, like: It should use Index X or a Hash Join instead of a nested loop.

Next thing is to figure out a way to make Oracle use that execution plan. Often by using Hints, or creating additonal indexes, sometimes changing the SQL statement. Then of course test that the changed statement

a) still does what it is supposed to do

b) is actually faster

With b it is very important to make sure you are testing the correct use case. A typical pit fall is the difference between returning the first row, versus returning the last row. Most tools show you the first results as soon as they are available, with no direct indication, that there is more work to be done. But if your actual program has to process all rows before it continues to the next processing step, it is almost irrelevant when the first row appears, it is only relevant when the last row is available.

If you find a better execution plan, the final step is to make you database actually use it in the actual program. If you added an index, this will often work out of the box. Hints are an option, but can be problematic if a library creates your sql statement, those ofte don't support hints. As a last resort you can save and fix execution plans for specific sql statements. I'd avoid this approach, because its easy to become forgotten and in a year or so some poor developer will scratch her head why the statement performs in a way that might have been apropriate with the data one year ago, but not with the current data ...

Answer (score -1):

***analyzing the oI also highly recommend the book Optimizing Oracle Performance, which discusses similar tools for tracing execution and utput.***