# Explain Plan for Query in a Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle

I have a stored procedure that consists of a single select query used to insert into another table based on some minor math that is done to the arguments in the procedure.  Can I generate the plan used for this query by referencing the procedure somehow, or do I have to copy and paste the query and create bind variables for the input parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [SQL Trace and TKPROF](http://68.142.116.68/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm#i4640). For example, open SQL*Plus, and then issue the following code:-

```
alter session set tracefile_identifier = 'something-unique'
alter session set sql_trace = true;
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';

select 'right-before-my-sp' from dual;
exec your_stored_procedure

alter session set sql_trace = false;
```

Once this has been done, go look in your database's UDUMP directory for a TRC file with "something-unique" in the filename. Format this TRC file with TKPROF, and then open the formatted file and search for the string "right-before-my-sp". The SQL command issued by your stored procedure should be shortly after this section, and immediately under that SQL statement will be the plan for the SQL statement.

**Edit:** For the purposes of full disclosure, I should thank all those who gave me answers on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104066/how-do-i-troubleshoot-performance-problems-with-an-oracle-sql-statement) last week that helped me learn how to do this.

Comment: I gotta pass it on to others on the group here, they got me started on SQL Trace and TKPROF just last week.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, this was done on purpose. The idea is that individual queries within the procedure are considered separately by the optimizer, so EXPLAIN PLAN doesn't make sense against a stored proc, which could contain multiple queries/statements.

The current answer is NO, you can't run it against a proc, and you must run it against the individual statements themselves. Tricky when you have variables and calculations, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Many tools, such as Toad or SQL Developer, will prompt you for the bind variable values when you execute an explain plan. You would have to do so manually in SQL*Plus or other tools.

You could also turn on SQL tracing and execute the stored procedure, then retrieve the explain plan from the trace file.

Be careful that you do not just retrieve the explain plan for the SELECT statement. The presence of the INSERT clause can change the optimizer goal from first rows to all rows.