# How to list all the tables used in a particular stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I Need to get the list of all the tables that is used in a particular stored procedure in oracle. how to get that list using query?

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/122817/2970947).

Comment: I don't know the specifics of Oracle, but there should be some way to retrieve the execution plan for the SP without actually executing it.  That would tell you what you wanted to know (and a good bit more).

Comment: @Lotharyx stored procedures themselves do not have execution plans, although the queries that they contain may.

Answer (score 3):

`Dynamic SQL`s are skipped, since they're not validated in `SEMANTIC` checks during compilations

```
select 
   proc_syn.referenced_owner, 
   proc_syn.referenced_name, 
   proc_syn.referenced_type,
   syn_tab.table_name
from 
   dba_dependencies proc_syn, dba_synonyms syn_tab, dba_tables tables
where 
     proc_syn.name= 'YOUR_PROC' 
  AND REFERENCED_TYPE in ( 'SYNONYM','TABLE')
  AND proc_syn.referenced_name = syn_tab.synonym_name
  AND syn_tab.synonym_name = tables.table_name
  AND syn_tab.owner = 'PUBLIC'
order by 
  proc_syn.referenced_owner, syn_tab.table_name;
```

Comment: add  proc_syn.name= 'PROC_NAME'

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   referenced_owner, 
   referenced_name, 
   referenced_type
from 
   dba_dependencies
where 
   name= 'PROC_NAME' AND REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE'
order by 
   referenced_owner, referenced_name, referenced_type;
```

Comment: did you replaced PROC_NAME with your procedure name? I have tried and it's working

Comment: yes i replaced it with my sp name but it's not giving the results

Comment: Show your exact code, and note that objects referenced in dynamic sql will not be included.