# How to identify all stored procedures refering a particular table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, package, procedure

I am working with Oracle 12c and need to find all references where a specific table or view is being used in *Stored Procedure/Function* and *packages*.

I have found a this [answer about MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272157/how-to-identify-all-stored-procedures-refering-a-particular-table), but it's **not** related to **Oracle**, besides `sp_help` and `sp_depends` sometimes return inaccurate results.

I know to search in column `text` of table `all_source`, for example, this code (search only standard user defined package names, not system package):

```
SELECT   type, name, line, text 
   FROM  all_source 
   WHERE type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
     AND name like 'P%' 
     AND UPPER(text) like '%' || p_table_or_view_name || '%'
   ORDER BY name, line;
```

but I'm looking if there's a more elegant and/or standard solution in **Oracle**.

I'm also checking if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236433/how-to-list-all-the-tables-used-in-a-particular-stored-procedure-in-oracle) can help me in any way.

I will appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`ALL_DEPENDENCIES`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1041.htm#i1576452) dictionary table:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE  referenced_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND    owner           = 'YOUR_USER';
```

Comment: Also, it would be good if you use admin user login which. Normal user may not have access to list the dependencies.

Comment: This solution will not list the stored (sub) programs where the table is referred in dynamic SQL.