# Optimize very long stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, optimization

I have stored procedure like this. I am posting body of procedure it has too many parameters and I have to many control for cheking warehouse activities. 
And it becomes huge and I cant control it. What ll be the best aproach for optimizing this.

```
DECLARE @ORDERFICHEREF INT =488
DECLARE @STFICHEREF INT =560
DECLARE @CLIENTREF INT =608
DECLARE @BARCODE VARCHAR(50)='1536011000010'
DECLARE @ISPARTIAL BIT=0
DECLARE @TERMINALREF INT=1
DECLARE @PARAMETERREF INT=0
DECLARE @PARTIALAMOUNT FLOAT=1
DECLARE @PARTIALUOMREF INT=59
DECLARE @PARTIALCONVFACT1 INT =1
DECLARE @PARTIALCONVFACT2 INT =50


DECLARE @RESULT INT
DECLARE @FICHENO VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @STATUS SMALLINT
DECLARE @BRANCH SMALLINT
DECLARE @SOURCEINDEX SMALLINT
DECLARE @BARCODEREF INT
DECLARE @ITEMREF INT
DECLARE @VARIANTREF INT
DECLARE @USREF INT
DECLARE @UOMREF INT
DECLARE @CONVFACT1 FLOAT
DECLARE @CONVFACT2 FLOAT
DECLARE @LSTAMOUNT FLOAT
DECLARE @USELABELUNITA INT
DECLARE @CHECKTYPE INT
DECLARE @ISEAN BIT
DECLARE @BARCODESPECODE VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PRICE FLOAT

SET @ISEAN=0
SET @CHECKTYPE =-1
SET @RESULT=0

DECLARE @SHIPINFOREF INT

SELECT @FICHENO =ORF.FICHENO,@STATUS=ORF.[STATUS],@BRANCH=ORF.BRANCH,@SOURCEINDEX=ORF.SOURCEINDEX
FROM ORDERFICHE ORF
INNER JOIN ORDERFICHE_TERMINAL ORFT ON ORF.LOGICALREF=ORFT.ORDERFICHEREF
WHERE ORF.LOGICALREF=@ORDERFICHEREF AND ORFT.TERMINALREF=@TERMINALREF

IF (@STATUS IS NULL OR (@STATUS NOT IN (0,1,6)))
BEGIN
SET @RESULT=14 --Fişe terminal atanmış ve fiş statusu tamamlandıdan küçük olacak
GOTO RESULT
END

SELECT
@BARCODEREF=LBL.LOGICALREF,
@ITEMREF=LBL.ITEMREF,
@VARIANTREF=LBL.VARIANTREF,
@UOMREF=LBL.UOMREF,
@USREF=LBL.USREF, 
@CONVFACT1 = LBL.CONVFACT1,
@CONVFACT2 = LBL.CONVFACT2,
@LSTAMOUNT=SUM(CAST(CAST(STL.AMOUNT*STL.CONVFACT2/STL.CONVFACT1*(2-IOCODE)/ABS(2-IOCODE) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT)),
@BARCODESPECODE = LBL.SPECODE
FROM LABEL_CARD LBL
LEFT OUTER JOIN STLINE STL ON LBL.LOGICALREF=STL.BARCODEREF AND STL.BRANCH=@BRANCH AND STL.SOURCEINDEX=@SOURCEINDEX
WHERE LBL.BARCODE=@BARCODE
GROUP BY LBL.LOGICALREF,LBL.ITEMREF,LBL.VARIANTREF,LBL.USREF,LBL.UOMREF,LBL.CONVFACT2,LBL.CONVFACT1,LBL.AMOUNT,STL.BRANCH,STL.SOURCEINDEX,LBL.SPECODE

--BARKOD - CARİ,SEVKİYAT ADRES KONTROLU
DECLARE @LABELCLINETREF INT
DECLARE @LABELLGORFICHEREF INT
DECLARE @LABELLGORFLINEREF INT
DECLARE @LABELSHIPINFOREF INT

IF(@BARCODEREF IS NOT NULL AND (SELECT CONVERT(BIT,VALUE) FROM ORDER_PARAMETER WHERE PARAMETERREF=86)=0)  --Cari hesap için yazdırılmış etiket farklı cariye satılsın mı?
BEGIN

SELECT @SHIPINFOREF=SHIPINFOREF FROM STFICHE WHERE LOGICALREF=@STFICHEREF

SELECT @LABELCLINETREF=CLIENTREF,@LABELLGORFICHEREF=LGORFICHEREF,@LABELLGORFLINEREF=LGORFLINEREF,@LABELSHIPINFOREF=SHIPINFOREF
FROM LABEL_CARD_LGREFERENCE WHERE BARCODEREF=@BARCODEREF AND ISCANCELLED=0

IF(@LABELCLINETREF<>@CLIENTREF)
BEGIN
SET @RESULT=57  -- BAŞKA CARİ İÇİN YAZDIRILMIŞ ETİKET
GOTO RESULT
END

IF (ISNULL(@LABELSHIPINFOREF,0)>0)
BEGIN
IF(ISNULL(@LABELSHIPINFOREF,0)<>ISNULL(@SHIPINFOREF,0))
BEGIN
SET @RESULT=58 -- SEVKİYAT ADRESLERİ FARKLI
GOTO RESULT
END
END
END

IF (@BARCODEREF IS NULL )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EANCHARCOUNT INT
    SELECT @EANCHARCOUNT=ISNULL(VALUE,0) FROM ORDER_PARAMETER WHERE PARAMETERREF=60
    IF @EANCHARCOUNT>0
    BEGIN
        SET @BARCODE=LEFT(@BARCODE,@EANCHARCOUNT)
    END

    SELECT @ITEMREF=UB.ITEMREF,@VARIANTREF=ISNULL(UB.VARIANTREF,0),@UOMREF=UB.UNITLINEREF,@USREF=ITM.UNITSETREF,@CONVFACT1 = IUA.CONVFACT1,@CONVFACT2 =IUA.CONVFACT2
    FROM {0}..LG_{1}_UNITBARCODE UB
    JOIN {0}..LG_{1}_ITEMS ITM ON ITM.LOGICALREF=UB.ITEMREF
    JOIN {0}..LG_{1}_ITMUNITA IUA ON IUA.UNITLINEREF=UB.UNITLINEREF AND IUA.LOGICALREF=UB.ITMUNITAREF AND UB.VARIANTREF=IUA.VARIANTREF
    WHERE  UB.TYP IN (0,1) AND UB.BARCODE=@BARCODE

    IF ISNULL(@ITEMREF,0)=0
    BEGIN
        SET @RESULT=1 --  @ITEMREF NULL GELİYORSA EAN BARKOD YOK  --Barkod LABEL_CARD'da ya sa UNITBARCODE da olmalı
        GOTO RESULT
    END

    SET @ISEAN=1
    SELECT @CHECKTYPE=CONVERT(INT,VALUE) FROM ORDER_PARAMETER WHERE PARAMETERREF=53
    IF(@CHECKTYPE=0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @LSTAMOUNT=SUM(CAST(CAST(AMOUNT*CONVFACT2/CONVFACT1*(2-IOCODE)/ABS(2-IOCODE) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT))
        FROM STLINE
        WHERE BRANCH=@BRANCH AND SOURCEINDEX=@SOURCEINDEX AND ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF AND BARCODEREF IS NULL
    END
    IF(@CHECKTYPE=1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @LSTAMOUNT=SUM(CAST(CAST(AMOUNT*(2.5-IOCODE)/ABS(2.5-IOCODE)*(UINFO2/UINFO1) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT))
        FROM {0}..LG_{1}_{2}_STLINE
        WHERE SOURCEINDEX=@SOURCEINDEX AND STOCKREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF AND CANCELLED=0 AND LPRODSTAT = 0 AND UINFO1>0 AND UINFO2>0
    END

    IF((SELECT CONVERT(BIT,VALUE) FROM ORDER_PARAMETER WHERE PARAMETERREF=54)=1)
    BEGIN
        SET @PARTIALAMOUNT=1
        SET @PARTIALUOMREF = @UOMREF
        SET @PARTIALCONVFACT1 = @CONVFACT1
        SET @PARTIALCONVFACT2 = @CONVFACT2
    END

    IF(@CHECKTYPE=1)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @BACKAMOUNT FLOAT
        SELECT @BACKAMOUNT=ISNULL(CAST(CAST(SUM(STL.AMOUNT*STL.CONVFACT2/STL.CONVFACT1) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT) ,0)
        FROM STLINE STL
        INNER JOIN ORDERFICHE ORF ON ORF.LOGICALREF=STL.ORDERFICHEREF
        WHERE ORF.STATUS<>3 AND STL.IOCODE=4 AND ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF AND BARCODEREF IS NULL AND ORF.SOURCEINDEX=@SOURCEINDEX

        SET @LSTAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT-@BACKAMOUNT
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --PARAMETEREREF=44
    IF((SELECT DBO.FNC_EXPIRATIONDATE (@BARCODEREF,44))=1)
    BEGIN
        SET @RESULT=46
        GOTO RESULT
    END
END

IF(@CHECKTYPE<>2)
BEGIN
    IF (@LSTAMOUNT IS NULL )
    BEGIN
        IF @CHECKTYPE=-1 AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
            FROM STLINE 
            WHERE BARCODEREF=@BARCODEREF AND (BRANCH<>@BRANCH OR SOURCEINDEX <> @SOURCEINDEX)
            GROUP BY BARCODEREF
            HAVING SUM(CAST(CAST(AMOUNT*(2-IOCODE)/ABS(2-IOCODE)*(CONVFACT2/CONVFACT1) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT))>0)
        BEGIN
            SET @RESULT=55 --Barkod başka bir ambarda
            GOTO RESULT
        END
        IF @CHECKTYPE=0 AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
            FROM STLINE 
            WHERE ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF AND BARCODEREF IS NULL AND (BRANCH<>@BRANCH OR SOURCEINDEX <> @SOURCEINDEX)
            GROUP BY ITEMREF,VARIANTREF,USREF
            HAVING SUM(CAST(CAST(AMOUNT*(2-IOCODE)/ABS(2-IOCODE)*(CONVFACT2/CONVFACT1) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT))>0)
        BEGIN
            SET @RESULT=55 --Barkod başka bir ambarda
            GOTO RESULT
        END
        IF @CHECKTYPE=1 AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
            FROM {0}..LG_{1}_{2}_STLINE 
            WHERE STOCKREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF AND CANCELLED=0 AND LPRODSTAT = 0 AND UINFO1>0 AND UINFO2>0 AND  SOURCEINDEX <> @SOURCEINDEX
            GROUP BY STOCKREF,VARIANTREF,USREF
            HAVING SUM(CAST(CAST(AMOUNT*(2.5-IOCODE)/ABS(2.5-IOCODE)*(UINFO2/UINFO1) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT))>0)
        BEGIN
            SET @RESULT=55 --Barkod başka bir ambarda
            GOTO RESULT
        END
        SET @RESULT=2 --Barkod Stokta olmalı - Girişi yapılmamış ürün
        GOTO RESULT
    END
    IF (@LSTAMOUNT<=0)
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STLINE WHERE STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND BARCODEREF=@BARCODEREF)
        BEGIN
            SET @RESULT=15 --Barkod Stokta olmalı - Mevcut emirde okutulmuş
            GOTO RESULT
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @RESULT=3 --Barkod Stokta olmalı - Çıkışı yapılmış
            GOTO RESULT
        END
    END
END

IF((@ISPARTIAL=0 OR @ISEAN=1) AND @PARTIALAMOUNT IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @LSTAMOUNT=@PARTIALAMOUNT
    SET @UOMREF = @PARTIALUOMREF
    SET @CONVFACT1 = @PARTIALCONVFACT1
    SET @CONVFACT2 = @PARTIALCONVFACT2
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERLINE WHERE ORDERFICHEREF=@ORDERFICHEREF AND STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ORLCOUNT INT
    SELECT @USELABELUNITA=USELABELCARDUNITA FROM LABEL_PARAMETERS WHERE LOGICALREF=1
    SELECT @ORLCOUNT=COUNT(LOGICALREF) FROM ORDERLINE WHERE STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF AND USREF = @USREF

    IF (ISNULL(@ORLCOUNT,0)=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @RESULT=13 --ITEMREF emirde olmalı
        GOTO RESULT
    END

    IF (@ISEAN=1 AND ISNULL(@PARTIALAMOUNT,0)=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @RESULT=11
        GOTO RESULT
    END

    IF(@ISPARTIAL=0 AND @ISEAN=0)
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM ORDERLINE ORL
        INNER JOIN LABEL_CARD_UNITA LBLA ON LBLA.BARCODEREF = @BARCODEREF AND ORL.UOMREF = LBLA.UOMREF
        WHERE ORL.STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ORL.ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND ORL.VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF)
        BEGIN   
            IF @USELABELUNITA=1
            BEGIN
                SET @RESULT=54 --etiket birim miktarı girilmelidir.
                GOTO RESULT
            END
        END

        DECLARE @TOAMOUNT FLOAT
        DECLARE @TSAMOUNT FLOAT

        SELECT @TOAMOUNT=CAST(CAST(SUM(ORL.AMOUNT*CASE WHEN LCU.LOGICALREF IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN @USELABELUNITA =1 THEN 0 ELSE ORL.CONVFACT2/ORL.CONVFACT1 END ELSE LCU.CONVFACT2/LCU.CONVFACT1 END)AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT)
        FROM ORDERLINE ORL 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LABEL_CARD_UNITA LCU ON LCU.BARCODEREF = @BARCODEREF AND ORL.UOMREF = LCU.UOMREF
        WHERE ORL.STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ORL.ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND ORL.VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF

        SELECT @TSAMOUNT=CAST(CAST(SUM(STL.AMOUNT*(STL.CONVFACT2/STL.CONVFACT1))AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT)
        FROM ORDERLINE ORL
        INNER JOIN STLINE  STL ON ORL.LOGICALREF = STL.ORDERLINEREF
        WHERE ORL.STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ORL.ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND ORL.VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF    

        --Parçalı seri barkod emir miktar aşımı kontrolü için parçalı miktar ana birime çevriliyor.
        DECLARE @MAINAMOUNT FLOAT
        SET @MAINAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT
        IF(@ISPARTIAL=0 AND @ISEAN=0 AND @PARTIALAMOUNT IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @MAINAMOUNT=@MAINAMOUNT*@CONVFACT2/@CONVFACT1
        END

        --IF (@MAINAMOUNT+ ISNULL(@TSAMOUNT,0)> ISNULL(@TOAMOUNT,0))  
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ORDER_PARAMETER WHERE PARAMETERREF=118 AND VALUE=0)
BEGIN
        IF (CAST(CAST((ISNULL(@MAINAMOUNT,0)+ISNULL(@TSAMOUNT,0))AS NUMERIC(28,6))AS FLOAT)> ISNULL(CAST(CAST(@TOAMOUNT AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT),0))
        BEGIN
            SET @RESULT=25 --Emir miktarı aşılmamalı
            GOTO RESULT
        END
END
    END

    IF((@ISEAN=1) AND @PARTIALAMOUNT IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @PTOAMOUNT FLOAT
        DECLARE @PTSAMOUNT FLOAT
        SELECT @PTOAMOUNT=ORL.AMOUNT,@PTSAMOUNT=CAST(CAST(SUM(STL.AMOUNT*(STL.CONVFACT2/STL.CONVFACT1))AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT) FROM ORDERLINE ORL
        LEFT OUTER JOIN STLINE STL ON ORL.LOGICALREF=STL.ORDERLINEREF
        WHERE ORL.STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ORL.ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND ORL.VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF AND ORL.UOMREF=@UOMREF
        GROUP BY ORL.LOGICALREF,ORL.AMOUNT
                        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ORDER_PARAMETER WHERE PARAMETERREF=118 AND VALUE=0)
BEGIN
        IF(CAST(CAST((@LSTAMOUNT + ISNULL(@PTSAMOUNT,0))AS NUMERIC(28,6))AS FLOAT) > ISNULL(@PTOAMOUNT,0))
        BEGIN
            SET @RESULT=25 --Emir miktarı aşılmamalı
            GOTO RESULT
        END
END
    END
END


DECLARE @FIFOCONTROL INT
SELECT @FIFOCONTROL=DBO.FNC_ENTRYDATE(@BARCODEREF,@BRANCH,@SOURCEINDEX,@PARAMETERREF)
IF @FIFOCONTROL>0
BEGIN
    SET @RESULT=24
    GOTO RESULT
END

IF(@ISEAN=0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ISCOUNTING SMALLINT
    SELECT @ISCOUNTING=DBO.FNC_ISCOUNTING(@BRANCH,@SOURCEINDEX,@ITEMREF,@VARIANTREF,@BARCODEREF)
    IF (@ISCOUNTING=2)   --SAYIMDA OKUTULMAMIS MALZEME
    BEGIN
        SET @RESULT=21
        GOTO RESULT
    END
END

IF (@ISPARTIAL=1 OR (@ISEAN=1 AND ISNULL(@PARTIALAMOUNT,0)=0))
BEGIN
    SET @RESULT=11 --miktar girilmeli
    GOTO RESULT
END

-- HAREKET ÖZEL KODU
DECLARE @SPECODE VARCHAR(50)
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ORDER_PARAMETER WHERE PARAMETERREF=101 AND VALUE=1)
BEGIN
    IF (@ISEAN=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SPECODE = @BARCODESPECODE
    END
    ELSE IF (@ISEAN=1)
    BEGIN
        SET @SPECODE = @EANSPECODE
    END
END

DECLARE @ORDERLINEREF INT
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @ORDERLINEREF=NULL

IF (ISNULL(@ORLCOUNT,0)>1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CUOMREF INT
    DECLARE @COAMOUNT FLOAT
    DECLARE @CSAMOUNT FLOAT
    DECLARE @CURRAMOUNT FLOAT
    DECLARE @CCONVFACT1 FLOAT
    DECLARE @CCONVFACT2 FLOAT

    DECLARE CURSOR_SORDER CURSOR FOR SELECT LOGICALREF,AMOUNT,UOMREF,CONVFACT1,CONVFACT2 FROM ORDERLINE WHERE STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF ORDER BY (CASE WHEN UOMREF=@UOMREF THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),ISNULL(LGORFICHEREF,2147483647)
    OPEN CURSOR_SORDER
    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_SORDER INTO @ORDERLINEREF,@COAMOUNT,@CUOMREF,@CCONVFACT1,@CCONVFACT2
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (ISNULL(@LSTAMOUNT,0)<=0)
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END
        SET @CURRAMOUNT=0
        IF((@ISEAN=1 OR @ISPARTIAL=0) AND @PARTIALAMOUNT IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @CURRAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT
            --SET @CONVFACT1 = @CCONVFACT1
            --SET @CONVFACT2 = @CCONVFACT2

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @CURRAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT*(CONVFACT1/CONVFACT2),@CONVFACT1=CONVFACT1,@CONVFACT2=CONVFACT2 FROM LABEL_CARD_UNITA WHERE BARCODEREF =@BARCODEREF AND UOMREF =@CUOMREF
        END

        IF (ISNULL(@USELABELUNITA,0)=0 AND @CURRAMOUNT =0)
        BEGIN
            SET @CURRAMOUNT = @LSTAMOUNT*@CCONVFACT1/@CCONVFACT2
            SET @CONVFACT1 = @CCONVFACT1
            SET @CONVFACT2 = @CCONVFACT2
        END
        SELECT @CSAMOUNT=ISNULL(SUM(CAST(CAST(AMOUNT AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT)),0) FROM STLINE WHERE STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ORDERLINEREF=@ORDERLINEREF AND ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF AND UOMREF=@CUOMREF

        IF (@COAMOUNT>@CSAMOUNT AND ISNULL(@CURRAMOUNT,0)>0)
        BEGIN
            IF (@COAMOUNT >= @CSAMOUNT + (@CURRAMOUNT))
            BEGIN
                SET @LSTAMOUNT=0
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @CURRAMOUNT = (@COAMOUNT - @CSAMOUNT)
                SET @LSTAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT-@CURRAMOUNT
            END
            SET @DATE=GETDATE()
            --SELECT 'bir', @STFICHEREF,8,4,@ITEMREF,@VARIANTREF,@BARCODEREF,@CURRAMOUNT,@CUOMREF,@USREF,@CONVFACT1,@CONVFACT2,@CLIENTREF,@BRANCH,@SOURCEINDEX,NULL,NULL,@DATE,@ORDERFICHEREF,@ORDERLINEREF,NULL,NULL,NULL,@TERMINALREF,@SPECODE
            EXEC MOB_STLINE_INSERT @STFICHEREF,8,4,@ITEMREF,@VARIANTREF,@BARCODEREF,@CURRAMOUNT,@CUOMREF,@USREF,@CONVFACT1,@CONVFACT2,@CLIENTREF,@BRANCH,@SOURCEINDEX,NULL,NULL,@DATE,@ORDERFICHEREF,@ORDERLINEREF,NULL,NULL,NULL,@TERMINALREF,@SPECODE

        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_SORDER INTO @ORDERLINEREF,@COAMOUNT,@CUOMREF,@CCONVFACT1,@CCONVFACT2
    END
    CLOSE CURSOR_SORDER
    DEALLOCATE CURSOR_SORDER
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LUSTAMOUNT FLOAT
    SET @DATE=GETDATE()
    IF (ISNULL(@ORLCOUNT,0)=1)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @OCONVFACT1 FLOAT
        DECLARE @OCONVFACT2 FLOAT
        SELECT @ORDERLINEREF=LOGICALREF,@UOMREF=UOMREF,@OCONVFACT1=CONVFACT1,@OCONVFACT2=CONVFACT2 FROM ORDERLINE WHERE STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF  
        IF((@ISEAN=1 OR @ISPARTIAL=0) AND @PARTIALAMOUNT IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @LUSTAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN


            SELECT @LUSTAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT*CONVFACT1/CONVFACT2,@CONVFACT1=CONVFACT1,@CONVFACT2=CONVFACT2 FROM LABEL_CARD_UNITA WHERE BARCODEREF =@BARCODEREF AND UOMREF =@UOMREF
            IF (@LUSTAMOUNT IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                SET @LUSTAMOUNT = @LSTAMOUNT*@OCONVFACT1/@OCONVFACT2
                SET @CONVFACT1=@OCONVFACT1
                SET @CONVFACT2=@OCONVFACT2
            END
        END
    END
    IF @LUSTAMOUNT IS NULL
    BEGIN
        IF((@ISEAN=1 OR @ISPARTIAL=0) AND @PARTIALAMOUNT IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @LUSTAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @LUSTAMOUNT=@LSTAMOUNT*@CONVFACT1/@CONVFACT2
        END
    END
    --SELECT 'iki', @STFICHEREF,8,4,@ITEMREF,@BARCODEREF,ISNULL(@LUSTAMOUNT,@LSTAMOUNT),@UOMREF,@USREF,@CONVFACT1,@CONVFACT2,@CLIENTREF,@BRANCH,@SOURCEINDEX,NULL,NULL,@DATE,@ORDERFICHEREF,@ORDERLINEREF,NULL,NULL,NULL,@TERMINALREF,@SPECODE
    EXEC MOB_STLINE_INSERT @STFICHEREF,8,4,@ITEMREF,@VARIANTREF,@BARCODEREF,@LUSTAMOUNT,@UOMREF,@USREF,@CONVFACT1,@CONVFACT2,@CLIENTREF,@BRANCH,@SOURCEINDEX,NULL,NULL,@DATE,@ORDERFICHEREF,@ORDERLINEREF,NULL,NULL,NULL,@TERMINALREF,@SPECODE
END


IF (@STATUS=0 OR @STATUS=6)
BEGIN
    UPDATE ORDERFICHE SET [STATUS]=1 WHERE LOGICALREF=@ORDERFICHEREF
    INSERT INTO RECORD_LOG (MODULEREF,RECORDID,IDENTITYINFO,USERREF,TERMINALREF,PROCESSDATE,[TYPE],[DESCRIPTION])
    VALUES (103,@ORDERFICHEREF,'Emir Numarası:' + ' ' + @FICHENO,NULL,@TERMINALREF,@DATE,16,'Durumu : Yükleniyor')
END

RESULT:
SELECT ISNULL(@RESULT,0) [RESULT]
IF (@ISPARTIAL=1 OR @ISEAN=1)
BEGIN
    SELECT ISNULL(@LSTAMOUNT,0) [LSTAMOUNT],@ISEAN [ISEAN],@CHECKTYPE [CHECKTYPE],(SELECT TOP 1 UOMREF FROM ORDERLINE WHERE STFICHEREF=@STFICHEREF AND ITEMREF=@ITEMREF AND VARIANTREF=@VARIANTREF ORDER BY (CASE WHEN UOMREF=@UOMREF THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),ISNULL(LGORFICHEREF,2147483647)) [ORDERUOMREF]

    IF(@ISEAN=1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT UNL.LOGICALREF,UNL.CODE,UNL.MAINUNIT,ISNULL(ORL.CONVFACT1,ITMA.CONVFACT1) [CONVFACT1],ISNULL(ORL.CONVFACT2,ITMA.CONVFACT2) [CONVFACT2],
        CASE WHEN ORL.LOGICALREF IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [ORDERUNIT],
        CASE WHEN  ITMA.UNITLINEREF = @UOMREF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [DEFAULTUNIT],
        ORL.AMOUNT - SUM(CAST(CAST(ISNULL(STL.AMOUNT,0) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT)) [OAMOUNT]
        FROM {0}..LG_{1}_ITMUNITA ITMA
        INNER JOIN {0}..LG_{1}_UNITSETL UNL ON ITMA.UNITLINEREF = UNL.LOGICALREF
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERLINE ORL ON ORL.ORDERFICHEREF = @ORDERFICHEREF AND ORL.STFICHEREF = @STFICHEREF AND ORL.ITEMREF = ITMA.ITEMREF AND ORL.VARIANTREF = ITMA.VARIANTREF AND ORL.UOMREF = ITMA.UNITLINEREF
        LEFT OUTER JOIN STLINE STL ON ORL.LOGICALREF = STL.ORDERLINEREF
        WHERE ITMA.ITEMREF = @ITEMREF AND ITMA.VARIANTREF = @VARIANTREF 
        GROUP BY UNL.LINENR,UNL.LOGICALREF,UNL.CODE,UNL.MAINUNIT,ORL.CONVFACT1,ITMA.CONVFACT1,ORL.CONVFACT2,ITMA.CONVFACT2,ORL.LOGICALREF,ITMA.UNITLINEREF,ORL.AMOUNT
        ORDER BY UNL.LINENR
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        IF((@USELABELUNITA=1 AND ISNULL(@ORLCOUNT,0)>0) OR (ISNULL(@ORLCOUNT,0)=0))
        BEGIN
            SELECT UNL.LOGICALREF,UNL.CODE,UNL.MAINUNIT,LBLA.CONVFACT1 [CONVFACT1],LBLA.CONVFACT2 [CONVFACT2],
                CASE WHEN ORL.LOGICALREF IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [ORDERUNIT],
                CASE WHEN  LBLA.UOMREF = @UOMREF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [DEFAULTUNIT],
                ORL.AMOUNT - SUM(CAST(CAST(ISNULL(STL.AMOUNT,0) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT)) [OAMOUNT]
            FROM LABEL_CARD_UNITA LBLA
            INNER JOIN {0}..LG_{1}_UNITSETL UNL ON LBLA.UOMREF = UNL.LOGICALREF
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERLINE ORL ON ORL.ORDERFICHEREF = @ORDERFICHEREF AND ORL.STFICHEREF = @STFICHEREF AND ORL.ITEMREF = @ITEMREF AND ORL.VARIANTREF = @VARIANTREF AND ORL.UOMREF = LBLA.UOMREF
            LEFT OUTER JOIN STLINE STL ON ORL.LOGICALREF = STL.ORDERLINEREF
            WHERE LBLA.BARCODEREF = @BARCODEREF 
            GROUP BY UNL.LINENR,UNL.LOGICALREF,UNL.CODE,UNL.MAINUNIT,ORL.CONVFACT1,LBLA.CONVFACT1,ORL.CONVFACT2,LBLA.CONVFACT2,ORL.LOGICALREF,LBLA.UOMREF,ORL.AMOUNT
            ORDER BY UNL.LINENR
        END
        ELSE IF(@USELABELUNITA=0 AND ISNULL(@ORLCOUNT,0)>0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM (
                            SELECT UNL.LINENR,UNL.LOGICALREF ,UNL.CODE,UNL.MAINUNIT,LBLA.CONVFACT1 [CONVFACT1],LBLA.CONVFACT2 [CONVFACT2],
                                CASE WHEN ORL.LOGICALREF IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [ORDERUNIT],
                                CASE WHEN  LBLA.UOMREF = @UOMREF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [DEFAULTUNIT],
                                ORL.AMOUNT - SUM(CAST(CAST(ISNULL(STL.AMOUNT,0) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT)) [OAMOUNT],ORL.LOGICALREF [ORDERLINEREF]
                            FROM LABEL_CARD_UNITA LBLA
                            INNER JOIN {0}..LG_{1}_UNITSETL UNL ON LBLA.UOMREF = UNL.LOGICALREF
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERLINE ORL ON ORL.ORDERFICHEREF = @ORDERFICHEREF AND ORL.STFICHEREF = @STFICHEREF AND ORL.ITEMREF = @ITEMREF AND ORL.VARIANTREF = @VARIANTREF AND ORL.UOMREF = LBLA.UOMREF
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN STLINE STL ON ORL.LOGICALREF = STL.ORDERLINEREF
                            WHERE LBLA.BARCODEREF = @BARCODEREF 
                            GROUP BY UNL.LINENR,UNL.LOGICALREF,UNL.CODE,UNL.MAINUNIT,ORL.CONVFACT1,LBLA.CONVFACT1,ORL.CONVFACT2,LBLA.CONVFACT2,ORL.LOGICALREF,LBLA.UOMREF,ORL.AMOUNT


                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT UNL.LINENR,UNL.LOGICALREF ,UNL.CODE,UNL.MAINUNIT,LBLA.CONVFACT1 [CONVFACT1],LBLA.CONVFACT2 [CONVFACT2],
                                CASE WHEN ORL.LOGICALREF IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [ORDERUNIT],
                                CASE WHEN  LBLA.UOMREF = @UOMREF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [DEFAULTUNIT],
                                ORL.AMOUNT - SUM(CAST(CAST(ISNULL(STL.AMOUNT,0) AS NUMERIC(28,6)) AS FLOAT)) [OAMOUNT],ORL.LOGICALREF [ORDERLINEREF]
                            FROM ORDERLINE ORL

                            INNER JOIN {0}..LG_{1}_UNITSETL UNL ON ORL.UOMREF = UNL.LOGICALREF
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN LABEL_CARD_UNITA LBLA ON ORL.UOMREF=LBLA.UOMREF
                                --AND ORL.UOMREF = LBLA.UOMREF
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN STLINE STL ON ORL.LOGICALREF = STL.ORDERLINEREF
                            WHERE LBLA.BARCODEREF = @BARCODEREF AND ORL.ORDERFICHEREF = @ORDERFICHEREF AND ORL.STFICHEREF = @STFICHEREF AND ORL.ITEMREF = @ITEMREF AND ORL.VARIANTREF = @VARIANTREF AND LBLA.LOGICALREF IS NULL
                            GROUP BY UNL.LINENR,UNL.LOGICALREF,UNL.CODE,UNL.MAINUNIT,ORL.CONVFACT1,LBLA.CONVFACT1,ORL.CONVFACT2,LBLA.CONVFACT2,ORL.LOGICALREF,LBLA.UOMREF,ORL.AMOUNT

            ) AS A
            ORDER BY A.LINENR
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: This *closed* [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783/favourite-performance-tuning-tricks) here may help you.

Comment: Thanks @GeomanYabes but i dont need any performance now it returns immediatly on huge data but the logic is too long. I think i have to slice this sp on every if and I write additinal sps for this thank for this topic its very nice by the way

Comment: @arachnida, you should not expect someone spend hours on this long script which is specific to your business logic.

Comment: @flicker I think you just misunderstand me i dont want they convert this lighter version I just need an idea last night I found my solution and convert my script. I wrote addition sp for every logic part.

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy I just make every logic as sperate sp.

Before

```
SELECT @FICHENO =ORF.FICHENO,@STATUS=ORF.[STATUS],@BRANCH=ORF.BRANCH,@SOURCEINDEX=ORF.SOURCEINDEX
FROM ORDERFICHE ORF
INNER JOIN ORDERFICHE_TERMINAL ORFT ON ORF.LOGICALREF=ORFT.ORDERFICHEREF
WHERE ORF.LOGICALREF=@ORDERFICHEREF AND ORFT.TERMINALREF=@TERMINALREF

IF (@STATUS IS NULL OR (@STATUS NOT IN (0,1,6)))
BEGIN
    SET @RESULT=14 --Fişe terminal atanmış ve fiş statusu tamamlandıdan küçük olacak
    GOTO RESULT
END
```

After

```
EXEC PRX_MINT_FICHE_STATUS_CONTROL @ORDERFICHEREF,@TERMINALREF,@RESULT OUTPUT,@FICHENO OUTPUT,@BRANCH OUTPUT,@SOURCEINDEX OUTPUT
IF @RESULT>0 
GOTO RESULT;
```

I write same code in the procedure i create output variables which i needed for next steps.